# Are there instances in which try-with-resources shouldn't be used over the regular try block?

Tags: java, oop, try-catch, try-with-resources

For example, what if an instance of a resource needs to be passed in throughout different objects?

Since try-with-resource's design was (rightfully) built to limit the scope of its members, how would someone deal with that kind of design issue?

Still use try-with-resources and pass around an instance constantly?
Use regular try-catch-finally block and keep the member outside of its scope?

Comment: This sounds a bit abstract. Could you please add some example code to outline what you mean by the different options?

Answer (score 0):

From the DOC :
" A resource is an object that must be closed after the program is finished with it. The try-with-resources statement **ensures that each resource** is closed at the end of the statement. Any object that implements `java.lang.AutoCloseable`, which includes all objects which implement `java.io.Closeable`, can be used as a resource."

If you want a design in which you need the resource throughout, don't go for `try-with-resources`, instead keep the resource outside and use it inside simple `try-catch`.
But be sure you do necessary **CLEANUP** if you use this strategy

Additionally,you may have to write nested try-catch blocks more frequently if you are using traditional `try-catch`.(Closing a resource also throws an `Exception`)

Answer (score 0):

As Ray said, the problem is a bit abstract. Two scenarios comes to my mind:

- local references to resources: use try-with-resources
  You can pass the resource to other methods inside the try-block, of course.
- member variables referencing resources: consider to implement AutoCloseable, so that the instance of your class itself can be used in a try-with-resources block.

Answer (score 0):

No a try with resource should always be used and must be used when the closable object is created. Even if you have an object that is passed in, that means the caller must have a try-catch block in which it called your method. Then the outer caller's try-catch will close the object.